# Basic htaccess RewriteRule is ignored

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Very simple htaccess RewriteRule query, but it does not work.

```
URL: http://dev.mypage.com/one/
RULE: RewriteRule ^one/$ /new/url/ [R=301,L]
```

No errors are displayed, just redirect does not work.

mod_rewrite module exists.

Maybe i need something more?

Comment: Please show your complete `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^one/?$ /new/url/ [R=301,L]
```

> Rewrite configurations are not inherited by virtual hosts. This means
>   that you need to have a **RewriteEngine on** directive for each virtual
>   host in which you wish to use rewrite rules.
>   https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteengine